# Migrating Thales payshield 9000 to Azure Key vault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, hsm

We want to migrate `HSM keys` from `Thales paysheild 9000` to `Azure Key vault`. We would like to know if this migration is supported and if supported, what’s the migration approach and use cases where customers have already migrated to Azure. We have gone through the article https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/key-vault/key-vault-hsm-protected-keys.md, it talks about Thales nShield family but we are using https://www.thalesesecurity.com/products/payment-hsms/payshield-9000

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess is only Microsoft can answer this question with certainty since it is a specific product question.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent question, as Dan suggests you should contact Microsoft for clarification, but unfortunately I don't think it's possible.

Recapping, as I'm sure you are aware the purpose of HSM's is so that the keys are not exportable.

Microsoft (and I assume Thales) supports key backup: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/backupkey but it can only be restored to the same geographical area.

In the article you supplied it mentions "Key Exchange Key" in each geographical area, which I assume will mean that Microsoft will be using a different key to that of another install of an HSM.

Having said this I'm not a general HSM expert, these are just links I have come across over time using KeyVault.

Please do contact Microsoft as I would to be interested if this is possible, please post an answer once you have heard back or a Microsoft employee can perhaps answer directly.

On the Thales literature it states:

"With nShield BYOK for Microsoft Azure, your on-premises
nShield HSM generates, stores, wraps, and exports keys to the
Microsoft Azure Key Vault on your behalf"

http://go.thalesesecurity.com/rs/480-LWA-970/images/Thales-e-Security-Microsoft-Azure-UK-sb.pdf

Interestingly it says generates / stores which suggests a pre-created key could be migrated. However on the contray I'm guessing the export must happen using the "Key Exchange Key" and stored in both on-prem and exported for Azure at the same time, not on-prem first, in the BYOK process.

This blog post has keyvault team's contact details if it helps: https://blog.romyn.ca/key-management-in-azure/

Answer (score 0):

The migration of important keys, that are encrypted under current LMK on your Thales payshield on premises, is very straightforward process:

1- Use console command GC to generate new ZMK in a clear format component, this will be done by using key type to be 000 which is ZMK key type, and also to choose clear format components option use letter 'x' in GC command steps.

2-Repeat the GC command above 3 times to generate 3 different plaintext format components of the new ZMK.

3-Now, at your payshield 9000 HSM, use the console command FK which means Form Key from components, the result is the new ZMK encrypted under old LMK.

4-Use the command KE ,which means export key, to export the important data encryption keys (DEK), such as ZPK for example, which is encrypted under old LMK to be encrypted under the new ZMK. Note: in KE command here use key type to be 001 which is ZPK key type.

5- Now you need to manually distribute the same new ZMK to the other party that you are going to migrate to.

6- You can do this manual distribution to such an important key (new ZMK) by sending the 3 different plaintext format components, which you have generated earlier in step number 2, to three different security officers at your corporate, and for security reasons, no one can have the 3 components all together.

7- On the other entity that you wanted to migrate your keys to, which is Microsoft Azure Key Vault cloud service, Azure is offering securing your keys in a hardware HSM environmental of nShield type, which is general purpose HSM and it is not specific in payment transactions like Thales payshield HSM.

8 - Refer to Microsoft Azure key vault documents, to know how to form the new ZMK of the 3 different plaintext format components that you have generated before, and refer to nShield manuals also to check the command which is responsible for importing keys.

9- Now, your important keys such as ZPK which was exported under new ZMK, are now imported under the same ZMK, and finally stored encrypted under the new LMK of your nShield provided cloud service.

Comment: thanks for this. 

can we utilise a general purpose HSM for EMV related work ? like ARQC/ARPC ? PCI guidelines do not specifically prohibit general purpose HSM from being used. There are certain constraints (e.g. disallow trnslation of ISO Type 0 to Type 1), etc.